# Elasticsearch - if no match use next query

Tags: elasticsearch

I've been looking for some days in the internet, but find no correct answer to my question. Maybe anyone can help?

If my query in elasticsearch have no hits they have to search in other fields. If there is an result, then show only these without searching in the other fields. My current solution is to boost the fields (ean,model,imodel), but the search in the other fields (title,desc) go on. So it returns hundreds of not relevant items.

```js
{
   "from": 0,
   "size": "16",
   "query": {
      "bool": {
         "should": [
            {
               "multi_match": {
                  "query": "63090300",
                  "fields": [
                     "ean^100",
                     "model^100",
                     "imodel^100"
                  ]
               }
            },
            {
               "match": {
                  "title_de": {
                     "query": "63090300",
                     "boost": "5"
                  }
               }
            },
            {
               "match": {
                  "title_de": {
                     "query": "63090300",
                     "type": "phrase",
                     "analyzer": "trigrams",
                     "fuzziness": "1"
                  }
               }
            },
            {
               "multi_match": {
                  "query": "63090300",
                  "fields": [
                     "desc_de"
                  ],
                  "operator": "and"
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Hey, just spilt you query into multiple. Have an exact match query and if that does not return any result do you heavy "fuzzy" query. Another thing is to use AND as the default operator insteat of OR. This makes you query behave more like google does: Only show docs, that contain every single term.

Comment: You're number codes look like they act as a (unique) identifier. Lookup of these is much faster using "Term" queries (but it has to be an exact match)

Comment: I can't figure out how you get hundreds  of results, since you specifiy a `size` of 16. I'm asking because specifying a `size` could get you closer to your goal. I mean, if you have 16 results with the first match, won't perform the others. Sure, it's not all-or-nothing, in the sense that if you have just 12 results, for instance, the other 4 will be searched with the additional matches. Does this all make sense?

Comment: Hay! Thanks for reply!!!
@Mario
yes, size is 16, but this is only for show not all results (eg. scrolling).

Have anyone an example or link to a helpful site (with examples ;) )?